File Transfers in Swift via WatchConnectivity
I am using WatchConnectivity to communicate between my Apple Watch and iPhone, specifically the fileTransfer(_:metadata:) method. I have a WatchConnectivityManager class that has both devices as targets and contains the following relevant functions:
final class WatchConnectivityManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    static let shared = WatchConnectivityManager()
    
    @Published var notificationMessage: NotificationMessage? = nil
    @Published var receivedRound: Round? = nil
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            WCSession.default.delegate = self
            WCSession.default.activate()
        }
    }
        
    func sendFile<T: Codable>(_ structData: T, fileName: String, fileType: String) {
            // 1. Serialize the struct to JSON
            guard let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(structData) else {
                os_log("Failed to encode struct to JSON", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
                return
            }
            
            // 2. Save the file in a temporary directory
            let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            do {
                try jsonData.write(to: tempURL)
            } catch {
                os_log("Failed to write JSON data to file: %{public}@", log: OSLog.default, type: .error, String(describing: error))
                return
            }
            
            // 3. Transfer the file
            if WCSession.default.activationState == .activated {
                WCSession.default.transferFile(tempURL, metadata: ["fileType" : fileType])
                os_log("File transfer initiated: %{public}@", log: OSLog.default, type: .info, fileName)
            } else {
                os_log("WCSession is not activated. Cannot send file.", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
            }
        }
}


I then created two views, one for the phone and one for the Apple Watch, which will create a custom struct that I made, convert it to a file, and then transfer the file across devices. When I transfer a file from the phone to the Apple Watch, I get a success. If I transfer from the watch to the phone, I get an error:
[WCFileStorage persistOutgoingFileTransfer:] error serializing file transfer ... due to Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4866 "Caught exception during archival: This object may only be encoded by an NSXPCCoder.

I have tried changing the structs to classes that inherit NSObject, NSCoding, and NSSecureCoding, but that made the problem worse, so I reverted back to using structs and serializing them with JSONEncoder. In my test views, it appears as if I am able to transfer files in both ways because the views will update with the correct information that I send. However, I always get the same error when trying to transfer files from watch to phone

From this thread it seems that the error message is a known issue and can be ignored.  Data is still transferred.
